# Python 2.7: Compare two days/months --> get the later one

Tags: python-2.7

I have a question regarding the comparison of two dates.
Given a list of workdays (meaning monday to friday) i have to check if the next day in the list is a new month or year.

I think doing this for years is somehow simple by doing something like:

```
if current_date.year < next_date.year:
    print "new year"
```

The same might work for months in one year. However, with the start of a new year the number of the month will be lower than the previous month number (12 vs. 1).

My question:
Is there a simple way to just check if a new month has started?

Comment: `if next_date.month != current_date.month`?

Comment: probably this happens when you work on one issue for hours xD Yeah that's just ist. Thanks for the answer ;)